# Backbone routes: optional parameter not matching

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I am using the following configuration for my router:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
                'item/:param(/:param-2)': 'func1',

                // Default
                '*actions': 'defaultAction'
            }
        });
```

I initialize the router as follows:

```
    var router = new Router;

    router.on('route:func1', function(param1, param2){
        console.log("Route: summary, class_id: " + class_id);

    });
```

But only URLs of the format **#item/1** are matched by the func1 route.

URLs like **#item/1/3** are passed to the defaultAction route.

I'm not able to figure out why the optional parameter doesn't get matched.

Comment: I figured it out eventually. "-" is apparently not allowed in routes.

Comment: It worked when I replaced the "-" with "_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others, the "-" character is not allowed in a **parameter name**. (Although it is allowed to be part of a **route**.)

You can replace "param-2" with "param_2" and it will work.